# Finding the maximum and minimum of a multivariable function on a domain

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

I recently asked a similar question to this here:
[Find the max and min values of a multivariable function on the boundary of a domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4209215/928623)

I thought I understood it and would be able to do questions like the one in my previous post, however, I've run into issues again and I'm not entirely sure where I went wrong.

I have the function: $$f(x,y) = y^3 + 3x^2y - 6x^2 - 6y^2 +2$$

I want to find the maximum and minimum of this function on the boundary of the domain $x^2 + y^2 =1$ using the method of Lagrange multipliers.

I started by finding $f_x = 6xy-12x$ and $f_y=3y^2 +3x^2-12y$

I then set $g = x^2 +y^2$ ($g=1$)

I know that $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$ so I set $(6xy-12x,3y^2+3x^2-12y)=\lambda (2x,2y)$

I then set $\lambda 2x=6xy-12x$ and found $\lambda = 3y-6$, I then subbed $\lambda$ into $3y^2 +3x^2-12y = \lambda 2y$ and got $y^2 = x^2$

I then tried to sub this into my objective function (I subbed all $x^2$ values for $y^2$) but I got an equation that I can't factorise to find values for: $4y^3-12y^2+2$ which leads me to believe I've made a mistake somewhere.

I'm not entirely sure where I made the mistake so if anyone could point out to me where I went wrong and show me what I should have done it would really help.

Comment: When you sub the equation that you've already found into the constraint function, what you get is x^2 + y^2 = 1 where x^2 = y^2, isn't it? Then from there, you can find the values of pairs (x,y). Finally, you just need to sub the points (x,y) to the function f.

Comment: So the equation I found: $4y^3 -12y^2+2$ isn't incorrect? And how would I sub that quadratic equation into my constraint function?

Comment: You find (*) x^2 = y^2 ,right? I do not understand how you found the part 4y^3...,  but after you find the equation (*), just say that x^2 + x^2 = 1, then 2x^2 = 1 and you finally get the values of x and y that satisfy this. Then you just put the pairs (x,y) into f(x,y). By the way how did you get the part 4y^3-12y^2+2?

Comment: Oh that makes sense, to get the equation I got I did something similar to you. You took $x^2 = y^2$ and then replaced $y^2$ in the equation of $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, I took $x^2 = y^2$ and replaced $x^2$ with $y^2$ in the original function: $y^3 +3x^2y - 6x^2 - 6y^2 +2$ since this is what I had to do in the question I asked last time

Comment: So I had my new function to be: $y^3 +3(y^2)y -6(y^2)-6y^2+2$

Comment: I'm looking at the solutions (the working out is not given) and they have $4$ points to test, the two I get from what you've shown me $(\sqrt{1/2},\sqrt{1/2}),(-\sqrt{1/2},-\sqrt{1/2})$ but they also show $(0,1)$ and $(0,-1)$ as solutions, any idea how they got these 2 points?

Comment: $ 2 \lambda x=6xy-12x \implies \lambda = 3y - 4$ when $x \ne 0$. You need to check $x = 0$ case separately.  Also, $3y^2 +3x^2-12y = 2 \lambda y \implies 3 - 12 y = 2 y (3y-4) $ as $x^2 + y^2 = 1$

Comment: As I said above, $x = 0$ is a solution to $2 \lambda x=6xy-12x$ and at $x = 0, y = \pm 1$.

Comment: Shouldn't $\lambda$ be $3y-6$? since we are doing $6xy-12x/2x$?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now, I need to check for $x=0$ separately when I'm handling the $\lambda$ part of the question. Ok thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You get 6 points there and the final step is just plugging these into the original function f(x, y).